# Android SDK Manager no downloader lib

Tags: android, sdk

in Android SDK I can not find Google Market Apk Expansion package. So I can not include downloader library into my project.
There is Google Market Licensing Package.

Does anybody know where is the problem? Or can anybody upload the lib?

Screenshot: http://imgupload.sk/viewer.php?file=nkcbzgpi736cpalyn43n.jpg

**EDIT**
Problem solved, Ive downloaded new SDK installer v18 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This path maybe helpful for you...

```
\Android\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\play_apk_expansion
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what Im looking for, except that there is no such folder, because Ive never downloaded it yet. Reason is clear - no such package in SDK Manager. Thats why Im asking for uploading those files :)